# Blender VSE slow regarding PC Capabilities

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, performance

I am quite a newbie at Blender (v2.79b) and I noticed something disturbing while generating videos.
I have 8C/16T, all the raw materials are on SSD and I can only see 1 core working on my machine with a 10% load on my CPU. I can see in the Task Manager that Blender has 40 threads but it seems only one is really working.
I make FullHD H264 lossless videos with Blender, compression is done with Handbrake in a second time.
I followed mostly video tutorials made by Mickeycal on YT to make the effects (cuts, speed, cross....). I use Blender Render.
Do you have clues to speed up Blender's performance ?
KR,
OLM

Comment: Thanks for the information. I've just successfully tested the Python script provided by Mikeycal Meyers, it works great!
https://github.com/mikeycal/the-video-editors-render-script-for-blender